# Xamarin iOS designer : There was a error rendering this document

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, rendering

I am working on Xamarin iOS app. I just recently update the Xamarin Studio to the `latest version 6.2` . but now I stuck at the below point.

My iOS designer can't work and it display the below error message.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The returned remote SDK entries are
>   invalid   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget.InitializeLocalFileStore ()
>   [0x00065] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4010/3a28108f/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/DesignerItems/IosSdkTarget.cs:90
>   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget..ctor (System.Version
>   xcodeVersion, MonoTouch.Design.DataPackEntry[] datapack, System.String
>   storeDirectory) [0x0004d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4010/3a28108f/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/DesignerItems/IosSdkTarget.cs:80
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+c__async12.MoveNext
>   () [0x00189] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4010/3a28108f/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:2015
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Error in ScreenShot :

[image]

**Xamarin Version :**

[image]

**XCode Version :**

[image]

Is there any workaround to solve it.

Comment: Could you post the full [version information](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#version-information) from Xamarin studio?

Comment: @PrashantC I update the question see my edit. I think the problem must be with Xcode update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an issue with latest XCode release, we do not support XCode v8.3 in the current stable release. (see https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-3/)

You may want to rollback to previous version of XCode to use the iOS designer

Comment: I actually do that thing I download previous version and try and then I check . Thanks for your same idea.

Comment: @Ironman We have fix available now. Please update your Xamarin installation

Answer (score 2):

Prashant C is correct. Updating to the latest version fixes it.

In addition when using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows I had the same issue.
Upgrading Xamarin (stable channel on mac & windows) and updating Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version (15.0.26228.12) fixed it for me.

see: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-3-support-for-vs-2017/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my opinion regarding this issue.
My best advice is to `NEVER` use the `IOS designer`. It's rubbish. Always use Xcode Interface Builder. The main reason is, you're guaranteed the storyboard will be valid with IOS. I once created an empty storyboard in IOS Designer and compared the XML it generated to an empty storyboard created in Xcode. It was totally different. The designer version was missing a hell of a lot of information. Since then I have never trusted the IOS designer. Not only that, but constraints are pain in the ass to use on the IOS designer, whereby, they're a lot easier in Xcode. I've also have storyboards render totally wrong in the IOS designer if the layout is particularly complex.